# Backbone.Marionette fill-in rendering for "live" information

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am using Backbone.Marionette and would like to re-render live information as it comes in. For example, the speed of a car as it accelerates and decelerates.

I already have the view set up to listen to changes to the model, but essentially, I need the model to listen to changes from the JSON every so often to see if the "speed" attribute is different. Would this be done simply be doing a setInterval on the model? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Found this for reference: http://weblog.bocoup.com/backbone-live-collections/

Comment: Firehose.io is also worth a look - http://firehose.io/